# How java compiler handles duplicates variable names. What mechanism it uses?

Tags: javacompiler

Does it uses any data structure in which duplicates are not allowed. What exactly is the logic behind it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it might help to read [tour] and [ask].  Could you edit your question to include at least one example?